# Is there a way to use OR inside a find method?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone using Express/MongoDB and I'm working on adding friends. I have it so when a user clicks a button on another users page that says "*Send Friend Request*" it sends a friend request to them and is stored inside a `FriendRequest` schema.

```
const friendRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  receiver: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"],
    default: "pending",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

The user is notified and they can either accept or deny the request. If they accept the friend request, the status changes from `pending` to `accepted`.

Here's where my code comes in.

I have a `friends` ejs page and I'm trying to map all `accepted` friends that a user has in their assigned `FriendRequest` schema. I'm planning on using this page to show a list of all a users friends. Example: `/:user/friends`.

```
router.get("/:user/friends", async function (req, res) {
  const user = req.user.username;

  const friends = await FriendRequest.find({
    sender: req.user.id, // my issue
    status: "accepted",
  })
    .populate("sender")
    .populate("receiver")
    .exec();
  res.render("friends", { user, friends });
});
```

There is my code. The problem has to do where it says `sender: req.user.id`. When I have it like that, it only shows a list of friends that I personally have sent friend requests to, and doesn't show any friends that have sent friend requests to me. And vice versa. If I change `sender` to `receiver` it will only show friends that have sent me friend requests.

Here's an example of an accepted friend when I use `console.log`. Each one is assigned either `sender` or `receiver`.

```
_id: new ObjectId("6471d4a3a705acadf8af8923"),
   sender: {
     friends: [],
     _id: new ObjectId("6454407483df47caef5004e2"),
     username: 'Dagger',
     createdAt: 2023-05-04T23:32:04.128Z,
     __v: 0
},
```

When I put both `sender: req.user.id` and `receiver: req.user.id` inside the code, nothing shows up at all. I've been trying to find a way to make it so if `sender` `OR` `receiver` is equal to `req.user.id` that it will show the username of the friend but I'm struggling to figure out a way because I can't use `||` inside the `find` method.

I want my code to look like this

```
const friends = await FriendRequest.find({
    sender || receiver: req.user.id,
    status: "accepted",
})
```

but in a way that won't give me errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to use `$or` operator.

[refer operators and projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/)

```
const friends = await FriendRequest.find({
    $or: [
         {sender: req.user.id},
         {receiver: req.user.id}
    ],
    status: "accepted"
})
```

OR

```
const friends = await FriendRequest.find({
    $and: [
         {$or: [
              {sender: req.user.id},
              {receiver: req.user.id}
          ]},
          {status: "accepted"}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a way to assign the `$or` to a variable? That way I don't have to put both `<%= friend.sender.username %>` and `<%= friend.receiver.username %>` in my `ejs` page.

Comment: No you can not do that